# making a 2D GameObject react to the position of another 2D GameObject

Tags: c#, position, transform, distance, unity-game-engine

So, my boss moves in a specific direction when it detects the player. The problem I'm having is how to get the boss to move depending on where the player is within a certain proximity. So if the boss is on the player's left, he'll move to the left. If he's on the player's right, he'll move to the right. But I can't figure out how to make him react based on distance. Right now I'm just doing a Debug.Log to save a few seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class phantom : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
public Transform Target;


void Start () 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}


void Update ()
{

    if (transform.position.x > Target.position.x ) {
        Debug.Log ("left");
    }
    if (transform.position.x < Target.position.x ) {
        Debug.Log ("right");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What reaction should happen based on distance? Have you tried calculating the distance in the update and taking various actions based on the result?

Comment: yea i have. i'm just gonna have the boss this script is attached to, move to the right or left. I already know how to do that. I'm focused on getting it to only show the Debug.Log (""); when she closes in at a certain proximity.

Comment: But what's the problem? I don't see any code here that is based on the distance to the target. Have you tried implementing any? If you have, what was the code, and what were the issues?

Comment: That's what I was trying to figure out. How to implement distance into the code. I figured it out though. I just turned the function into an OnTriggerStay2D function. Thanks for your responding though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just made the function not in Update but with an OnTriggerEnterStay2d (Collider2D other). Then I placed a trigger collider on the same GameObject and only when it detects the Target (the player) does the debug come up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Vector3.Distance method to determine the distance between your two object based on thier respective transform. That way, you can modify your boss's behavior according to his proximity to the player. The smaller the magnitude value is, the closer your two transforms are.

Ex:

```
int distanceYouWant;

if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.position).magnitude < distanceToDoStuff)
{
     Debug.Log("Boss do stuff!");
}
```

Here is the link to the Unity scripting API doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm sure that will be very useful in the future. Thanks for your help it's appreciated. I bookmarked the link for future use.